# Nested For Loop vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop, nested

If I would enter 5 to textbox, the answer would be like this

> 1
>  1 2
>  1 2 3
>  1 2 3 4
>  1 2 3 4 5

then if i would enter 10 or more the answer would be

> 1
>  1 2
>  1 2 3
>  1 2 3 4
>  1 2 3 4 5
>  1 2 3 4 5
>   6
>  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
>  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
>  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

my code:

```
Private Sub CmdOk_Click()

Dim a, b, c, d, z As Integer
z = TxtInput.Text

For a = 1 To z Step 1
List1.AddItem a
For b = 2 To z Step 1
List1.AddItem a & " " & b
For c = 3 To z step 1
List1.AddItem a & " " & b & " " & c
For d = 4 To z Step 1
List1.AddItem a & " " & b & " " & c & " " & d
Next d
Next c
Next b
Next a

End Sub
```

[image: Output of my code]

Comment: did you have a question?

Comment: @Plutonix His problem is probably that it isn't displaying properly on screen. But yes, he didn't write any question.

Comment: I had posted a simplest method below

Answer (score 2):

Why are you making it so complicated?

That is suppose to work :

```
Private Sub CmdOk_Click()

  Dim z as String = TxtInput.Text
  Dim ListTemporary as String = "1"

  For i = 2 To Integer.parse(z) Step 1
    ListTemporary = ListTemporary & " " & i.ToString()
    List1.AddItem ListTemporary
  Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub CmdOk_Click()     
 ListBox1.Items.Clear() ' clear the list before processing
  Dim s As String = "" ' initialize a string variable
  For i As Integer = 1 To CInt(TextBox1.Text) ' i loop for row counting
  s = "" ' in each itetration clear the s value
  For j As Integer = 1 To i ' for format the string to display in each index
  s = s & j & " " 
  Next
  ListBox1.Items.Add(s) ' add each item in row index
 Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line (edited for clarity)

```
List1.Items.AddRange(
    Enumerable.Range(1, Integer.Parse(Me.txtInput.Text)).
    Select(Of String)(
        Function(i)
            Return Enumerable.Range(2, i - 1).
                Select(Of String)(Function(i1) i1.ToString()).
                Aggregate(Of String)("1", Function(s1, s2) s1 & " " & s2)
        End Function).ToArray())
```

As a side-note, this approach is about twice as fast as the other answer, important if the number gets large.

Comment: This isn't http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/. But nice one anyhow. (Good luck debugging that afterward though...)

Comment: @Sifu Thanks. Mine's twice as fast as yours.

Comment: I don't doubt that yours is much much much faster than mine. It's like comparing the size of `Jquery.js` and `Jquery.min.js`, sure the minimized version is lighter and faster, but can you understand anything in it? All I was saying, is that it is much harder to understand what is going on in your answer, even though it is much more efficient and faster.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Try this.

```
List1.Items.Clear()
    Dim i, j, z As Integer
    Dim x, a As String
    z = TxtInput.Text
    For i = 1 To z
        For j = 1 To i
            x = Convert.ToString(j)
            a = a & " " & x
        Next
        List1.Items.Add(a)
        a = ""
    Next
```